# Create a test database for e2e testing in knex

Tags: mysql, sql, query-builder, knex.js

I'm trying to create a database that needs to start empty and, in each e2e test case will receive some data. I tried this:

```
const createTable = async (
  name: string,
  callback: (table: Knex.CreateTableBuilder) => void
) => {
  return db.schema.createTable(name, async (table) => {
    table.engine("memory");
    callback(table);
  });
};

const restartDb = async () => {
  await db.schema.dropTableIfExists("BudgetItem");
  await db.schema.dropTableIfExists("Budget");
};

export const startDb = async () => {
  await restartDb();

  await createTable("Budget", (table) => {
    // ...database schema that has
  });

  await createTable("BudgetItem", (table) => {
    // ...database schema that has
    table
      .integer("budgetId")
      .unsigned()
      .notNullable()
      .references("id")
      .inTable("Budget"); // it have FK to Budget table
  });
};
```

And in each test I call this function here:

```
export const useTestDb = () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await startDb();
  });

  afterAll(async () => {
    await db.destroy();
  });
};
```

But this is causing some nondeterministic behavior, most of the time it says that one table doesn't exist, others it says that the table already exists,s and a few times it works.

Why is this happening? How can I create this test Db;

Comment: I think you forgot the `await` before the `restartDb`, now it is not waiting for the promises of dropping the tables to resolve and already trying to create new ones.

Comment: awaiting for the promise didn't solve the problem. I'm still getting non-deterministic behavior.

Comment: I thikn converting your `startDb` function will be good as well now the `beforeEach` hook will be finished before the callbacks are called

Comment: To something like `return new Promise(resolve => { db.schema.createTable(name, table => { table.engine("memory"); resolve(table) }) });`

Comment: Didn't work. I think this is a problem with MySQL itself, since running `await db.raw` to DROP and creating the tables produce the same behavior.